# Show array data from ajax data in div using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using ajax to fetch the data from database. There are about 20 records in database. Here is the php code to fetch the data.

```
$query = "SELECT user_id,website,emailid FROM job_posting where uid = ? order by date DESC";

        $result = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $result ->bind_param("i",$uid);
        $result->execute();
        $result->store_result();

        $result->bind_result($user_id,$website,$emailid);
        if($result->num_rows >0){

                while ($result->fetch()) {

                    $website = $website;
                    $emailid = $emailid;
                    $user_id = $user_id;

                    $data['content'][] = array(

                    'website' => $website,
                    'emailid' => $emailid,
                     'user_id' => $user_id,  
                    );



                }
             $data['success'] = 'true'; 
     }
     echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Above code is working fine. I can see the data in json format.  Sample below.

```
{"content":[{"website":"test.com","emailid":"none@none.com","user_id":1},{"website":"test.com","emailid":"none@none.com","user_id":2},{"website":"test.com","emailid":"none@none.com","user_id":3}],"success":"true"}
```

Now I want to show this data by angular in webpage.

Angular code:

```
     $http({
                        url: 'get_details.php',
                       method: "GET",
                        params: {uid: uid}
                    })
                        .success(function(data) {

                            if (data.success) {

}
```

Please advise how to show the array data in a div.

```
<div class="col-md-12>
Need to show website, email id and user id in this div.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use then instead success . success and error have been deprecated and will be removed in v1.6.0.

```
 $http({
                        url: 'get_details.php',
                       method: "GET",
                        params: {uid: uid}
                    })
                        .then(function(data) {
                   $scope.data = data.data.content

}
```

and in div

```
<div class="col-md-12 ng-repeat="x in data >
{{x.emailid}} - {{x.userid}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this.(but its better use `then` function instead of `success`)

```
$http({
          url: 'get_details.php',
          method: "GET",
          params: {uid: uid}
       })
       .success(function(data) {
          $scopemyData = data.content;
        }
```

and in view

```
   <div ng-repeat="data in myData">
     <span>{{data.website}}</span>
     <span>{{data.emailid}}</span>
     <span>{{data.user_id}}</span>
   </div>
```